# not able to parse the json (unstructured) in R

Tags: r, json, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I am trying to parse the json column using below mentioned dataframe:

```
ID         Json_Data
ABC-123    {}
AXD-456    {}
AET-789    {}
```

I am using below mentioned code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

    json_file <- lapply(df$Json_Data, function(x) {
      x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
      unlist(x)
    })

 Output<-data.frame(json_file = unlist(json_file))
```

I want that in case of unstructured json data it simply take a reference of first json file and create that much colums in the output w.r.t `ID`.

Just want to know, if is there any way to fetch the specific value by json header name??

- Below mentioned sample data are for one `ID`, for different IDs it could be 
  large or small with increasing/decreasing number of json header.

Sample Json Data:

```
"{
  ""headerSegment"": {
    ""A"": ""123"",
    ""B"": ""456"",
    ""C"": "" "",
    ""D"": ""15004"",
    ""date1"": ""08/06/2017"",
    ""time1"": ""164637""
  },
  ""seg1"": {
    ""nam"": ""arf"",
    ""date2"": ""01/01/1947"",
    ""sex"": ""Male""
  },
  ""ifd"": [
    {
      ""hse"": ""xrt"",
      ""val1"": ""123"",
      ""adft"": ""T""
    }
  ],
  ""ete"": [
    {
      ""ert"": ""9999"",
      ""ert1"": ""fdr"",
      ""eew"": ""E""
    }
  ],
  ""dfer"": [],
  ""ertd"": {
    ""dfe"": """"
  },
  ""Type"": [],
  ""sder"": {
    ""fig1"": ""erte"",
    ""adf"": ""14"",
    ""Dt"": ""08/06/2017"",
    ""Val1"": ""0-100""
  },
  ""Type2"": {
    ""fig2"": ""ert"",
    ""adfg"": ""20"",
    ""Dt2"": ""08/06/2017"",
    ""Val2"": ""980""
  },
  ""afdert"": [
    {
      ""age"": ""dfe"",
      ""ge"": ""ere"",
      ""aeer"": ""254"",
      ""ageer"": ""ere"",
      ""Date3"": ""08/06/2017"",
      ""aeee"": ""R""
    }
  ],
  ""ef"": [],
  ""ferr"": [],
  ""fere"": {}
}"
```

Comment: @Sathish Thanks, but my json data is very large, don't think that i can show it here. I am trying to parse it but not able to make it yet. What do you mean by `toJSON` function here??

Comment: @Sathish Updated the sample Json Data, but that is the only 1 sample against different different id we can have large or small json data with additional json header or less json header.